# want to show google reviews star on google search description

Tags: php, html, review

want to show google reviews star on google search description, as in this pic.

[image]

i have used this code. Kindly tell me. is that ok? or when i it will work? same time or after some hours.

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
   <span itemprop="name"></span>
   <div itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating">
     Rated <span itemprop="ratingValue"></span>/5 based on <span itemprop="reviewCount"></span> reviews
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](http://www.nosegraze.com/reviews-star-ratings-google-search-results/) article:

**Basic outline:**

```
<div itemprop="review" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Review">
    <meta itemprop="author" content="Ashley">

    <strong itemprop="itemreviewed">Sweet Peril</strong> by <a href="http://www.nosegraze.com/reviews/authors/wendy-higgins/">Wendy Higgins</a><br />

    Other book info can go in here...

    <strong>My Rating:</strong> <span itemprop="reviewRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Rating"><img src="http://www.nosegraze.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/three-stars.png" alt="3 Stars" class="stars" /><meta itemprop="ratingValue" content="3" /><meta itemprop="bestRating" content="5" /></span>
</div>
```

**Would return this:**

---

[image]